# JS parse ShowOpenDialog result set

Tags: javascript

In Javascript against `ShowOpenDialg` method, I am getting the following response:

```
"{"items":[{"id":"{168B874F-9CF7-E311-B136-00155D02101E}","name":"Test Account1 -     6/19/2014","html":"<nobr title=\"Test Account1 - 6/19/2014\" class=\"gridcellpadding\"><a  href=\"#\" id=\"gridBodyTable_primaryField_{168B874F-9CF7-E311-B136-00155D02101E}_0\"  target=\"_self\" title=\"Test Account1 - 6/19/2014\" class=\"ms-crm-List-Link\"  tabindex=\"6\">Test Account1 - 6/19/2014</a></nobr>","type":"1","values":" [{\"name\":\"name\",\"value\":\"Test Account1 - 6/19/2014\"}, {\"name\":\"accountnumber\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"primarycontactid\",\"value\":\"\"}, {\"name\":\"address1_city\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"telephone1\",\"value\":\"\"}, {\"name\":\"emailaddress1\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"fax\",\"value\":\"\"}, {\"name\":\"address1_name\",\"value\":\"\"}, {\"name\":\"address1_fax\",\"value\":\"\"}]","keyValues":"{\"name\": {\"name\":\"name\",\"value\":\"Test Account1 - 6/19/2014\"},\"accountnumber\": {\"name\":\"accountnumber\",\"value\":\"\"},\"primarycontactid\": {\"name\":\"primarycontactid\",\"value\":\"\"},\"address1_city\": {\"name\":\"address1_city\",\"value\":\"\"},\"telephone1\": {\"name\":\"telephone1\",\"value\":\"\"},\"emailaddress1\": {\"name\":\"emailaddress1\",\"value\":\"\"},\"fax\": {\"name\":\"fax\",\"value\":\"\"},\"address1_name\": {\"name\":\"address1_name\",\"value\":\"\"},\"address1_fax\": {\"name\":\"address1_fax\",\"value\":\"\"}}","category":null,"ambiguousRecordsXml":null,"sel ected":false,"displayclass":"","onclick":"openlui(new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));"}]}"
```

I need to retrieve `id` and `name` in first line of response.

How to do that in JS? The retrieval method should be generic because response may contain multiple records. This is the data of single record.

Thanks.

Comment: Check how to parse JSON in JS http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Answer (score 1):

I managed to extract value as follows:

```
obj = JSON.parse(dlgReturnValue); //dlgReturnValue is JSON object holds the result
var id = obj.items[0].id;
var name = obj.items[0].name;
```